# Did Endgame just hint about the Soul World?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

All the people, including Avengers, who dusted in the *Infinity War* are brought back in *Endgame*. But they didn't bring back Vision, Loki and Heimdall (as we haven't seen them in a movie except Loki in 2012).

So, are the dusted people just gone to the Soul World? When Spider-Man is talking to Iron Man he mentioned that when he dusted on Titan Dr. Strange was there with him and telling him "Hey, it's time, the Avengers need us". So, is it possible they just told us about the Soul World as the MCU has always this strategy that they give us a small himt about their future?

Comment: Vision, Loki and Heimdall weren't actually dusted, they were killed in other ways before that happened.  I also thought Spider-Man was talking more about after they had came back from being dusted, not being currently dusted.  I could be remembering that dialog wrong though.  I would guess this has little to nothing to do with the soul world.

Comment: Spider-Man was just explaining the experience of being dusted and then un-dusted -- it was as if he had just passed out briefly and then woken up to just him and Dr. Strange, who then told him the Avengers needed them and it had actually been 5 years.

Comment: @PawnInGameOfLife I said the same thing that the Gauntlet bring only the dusted people not who died before. And I am just seeing the possibility of Soul World. Why are you downvoting this question?

Comment: @deepakkumar  First, I didn't downvote.  Second when you mentioned they didn't bring those characters back I thought you you inferring that they should have been.  I can see now that you didn't necessarily mean that, my apologies (but again, I did not downvote).  In my defense, it looks like the current answer assumed the same thing.

Answer (score 7):

The Vision, Loki, Gamora, Heimdall and Black Widow were not dusted by the activation of the Infinity Stones during Infinity War - they were killed by individual actions taken by people. The undoing of the snap did not bring these characters or the missing Asgardians (from the Statesman, end of Ragnarok, the start of Infinity War) or any of the other planets that Thanos had manually culled back to life because the soul stone had played no part in killing them.

Once the un-snap occurred, Spider-Man has a conversation with Iron Man mid-battle and I believe you have misunderstood the context of what was said - Spider-Man was not explaining that he had been on Titan for five years after being dusted, he said he was on Titan in Infinity War and got dusted. Then suddenly (from his perspective) he was alive again, with Doctor Strange telling him that five years had passed and it was time.

Comment: If so then what's the place at the end of infinity war of Thanos and little Gamora?

Comment: @deepakkumar I guess it is kinda a soul world as per this [answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/186733/red-lake-with-gate-where-these-two-characters-meet-at-the-end-of-infinity-war). But there is Gamora in this place and she died "ordinary" death, not snapped away. Maybe it means that only dead people go there, and those snapped away went to different place?